# Roo project with mysql for heroku

Tags: java, mysql, heroku, spring-roo

Anyone faces problem with roo project that connect with mysql for heroku?? i would like to deploy my roo project using mysql database, and i follow some tutorial that heroku provided ,but it all seems does not work. I pushed all the files successfully and it gave me no error ,but when i open the website, it shows me application error...anyone here with this problem

Comment: Have you taken a look at your logs with the 'heroku logs' command?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this post thoroughly:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner